# Why is my Question still on hold after editing it extensively?

Tags: discussion

I have asked the following question : [How to redirect a User to a predefined URL next to a VBO (Views Bulk Operation) Operation?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272359/how-to-redirect-a-user-to-a-predefined-url-next-to-a-vbo-views-bulk-operation)
... and was put on hold on nov.13 by kiamlaluno.

I have extensively reedited my question, several times, since then (including a screen capture where my problem is highlighted), but it remains on hold (or closed ?) : how can I have it re-openned ?

Comment: I'd vote to close it again, since it's a bug report. And this belongs on drupal.org. Not here. Asking on DA if anybody else experienced this lacks the step to try to debug this yourself. We can't do this for you. Since we don't know your setup, your modules, your custom code and whatever else you configured on your page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> how can I have it re-openned ?

Whenever an on-hold question is edited, it goes into a queue for re-opening. For whatever reason, it hasn't gathered the re-open votes necessary from the natural process while in that queue.

But your edits have done the trick, it's now a well framed question, so there's no reason to keep it on hold any longer; I've re-opened it.

Comment: -1 as the mentioned issue is a bug report which should be posted on drupal.org instead. Which makes it off-topic for DA.

Comment: Thank you Clive for re-openning. I cannot know wether this is a bug or a misuse (since VBO is not extensively documented). I accept to be closed if it is actually a bug (just tell me where I should report it).

Comment: @leymannx I read it more as "have I configured this properly?", that's why I re-opened it. Thanks for talking the OP through it in the comments. having read it again I think you're right, without more info it's probably a bug report

Comment: @Jacques-MarieMoranne I understand your predicament, it's often difficult to know if something's a bug or not. I think in this case you've done what would probably be considered the obvious thing to configure the redirect, and it hasn't worked - if you don't have any more context than that to share, it's likely to be a bug in the module and needs to be reported to the issue queue (leymannx provided a link in the comments on the original question)